# Yii2 drop down pagination in GridView

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to make dorpdown pagination in yii2 gridview.
I tried this in my GridView, but don't clear what should the next step I do to do.

```
<label>
<?=     
    $form->field($model, 'pagesize')
    ->dropDownList(
        ["1"=>"1","10"=>"10","25"=>"25","50"=>"50","100"=>"100"],               
        )->label(''); 
    ?>&nbsp;&nbsp;records per page
</label>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $model,
        'filterSelector' => '#' . Html::getInputId($model, 'pagesize'),
        'columns' => [
            'id',
            'symbol',
            'code',
            'name',
.........
```