# Yiii2 Gridview show all records without pagination

Tags: php, gridview, pagination, yii2

I have working with Yii2.0, in my requirement i want to show all the records in my particular grid(with out pagination), i mean if suppose i having 250 records(row) means all the records will be list in that grid , then i want the custom combo-box to limit the records like(10,50,100) this.

**i want the combo-box**

[image]

do you have any idea and suggestion to implement as per the above requirement
Thanks in advance for your support and idea

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can set pagination as false so that you can display all records at once:

```
$dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
    'query' => Yii::@app->find()->all(),
    'pagination' => false,
]);
```

[Source](http://www.sitepoint.com/rendering-data-in-yii-2-with-gridview-and-listview/)

Then if you want to implement a combo-box to limit records, create a form that asks the limit then send the form to itself(or to which page that handles the query of records) and make the database query dynamic. Like:

```
    $limit = (isset(Yii::$app->request->post('limit'))?Yii::$app->request->post('limit'):'0');
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => Yii::@app->find()->where('user_id = :user_id')->limit($limit)->all(),
        'pagination' => false,
    ]);
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: i got the solution for the pagination, but i want the combo-box with in the grid , i updated the screen for your better understand.

Comment: @sen I see. That's tricky. Have you tried the answer to this post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27222297/yii2-drop-down-pagination-in-gridview

Comment: i used the pagination answer, but i want the combo-box list as per the my requirement do you have any idea regarding that

Comment: all I can think of is insert a dropdown list in the columns option in gridView